# How to change image size when pressing

Tags: android, image, imageview

I'm currently developing an android app and I would like to achieve an effect to which I haven't found an answer to, even after some searching.

The effect I would like to obtain is over an image. Usually when you press an image, you apply some sort of tint over the image in order to show some feedback, but I would like to go a little bit further, I wouldn't like to apply a tint but a sort os scale over the image.

E.g. I have the following image, [Normal Image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzC0L6HZl56TSmE5NXU2anFMbjQ/edit?usp=sharing), and if I press the image (and while I keep it pressed), I would like the image to shrink a bit, like this [Pressed Image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzC0L6HZl56TVHBHLW5RSWFDZFE/edit?usp=sharing)

N.B.- The black part would not be part of the image, but part of the background. The image would only be the blue square.

Thank you for any help! :)

P.S.- I couldn't post the images here because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Which API level are you compiling against? If it's API 11+ you could add onTouchListener to the ImageView and alter scaling based on touch events.

Comment: also ---- the infamous imagebutton perhaps :))) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Comment: @harism - Minimum 8, Target 15.

Comment: @SergeyBenner - ImageButton would be a solution, but I haven't exposed all the details, so I don't know if ImageButton would be the most suitable solution.

I currently don't have much time on my hands, but I have a solution that I'll implement and explain later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the onTouchListener of your ImageView that displays the image, so that it replaces the displayed image. This is the listener that runs when you press or unpress the view (in this case the image).

Sample Code:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
iv.setOnTouchListener(new ImageView.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            // Write code here that sets the imageview to display the pressed image
        else if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            // Write code here that sets the imageview to display the unpressed image
    }
});
```

Reference to onTouchListener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Reference to ImageView (for replacing the displayed image): 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

Comment: Yes, I understand and I know about onTouchListener. Maybe I didn't explain correctly my idea, I don't know. But it would be here the best place to scale the image? Is it using the matrix over the image?

Comment: tbkn, thank you, this is a possible solution if I intended to just switch between two images, one normal and one pressed. What I want is to resize the image, so I have only one image, and when I press it, I would be able to resize it. Like I said to SergeyBenner, I currently don't have much time on my hands, but I already have a solution that I'll implement and explain later.

Comment: You can use my code to change image size instead of changing displayed image... But as long as you found something that works, all's good.